# How to run an SBT project in IntelliJ Idea 2016.2.4?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

Many years have passed since development of Scala/SBT-IDEA integration began and the results are clearly visible. At the beginning I had been using pure Linux terminal to create and run an SBT project and an SBT extension to generate the IDEA boilerplate to be able to use Idea for writing the code only. Now as I am revisiting the Scala/SBT-IDEA stack it seems that all the job can be done from inside IDEA itself conveniently, [this page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/getting-started-with-sbt.html) describes how.

So, I have managed to create the project but I can't find how am I meant to run it. Can somebody help please?

I don't have installed Scala nor SBT as Idea seems have downloaded them itself (though I don't know where has it put them).

Comment: What have you tried so far and what error message did you get? I would recommend the following: navigate to any scala file (choose one that contains a main program if you have one). IDEA will let you know (with a message at the top of the file) if you don't have the correct setup yet. Just click the button and it will take care of everything for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply select, in the project browser, a class that has a static `main`, and from the context menu choose "Run". This will create the correct run configuration for you.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I was just confused with the global Run button grayed (and `sbt run` not working in the terminal pane). I didn't know I am to right-click a particular file to find the working Run button.